# QT Application UTF8-strings in translation get displayed erroneous

Tags: windows, c++11, encoding, utf-8, qt-linguist

We are using QT 5.5 successfully throughout our VC++ projects in VS2015.
Now, i am adding i18n thereto, using QTs Linguist tools to create my strings 2b translated and the resulting .qm files. I load the files through QTranslator object, the translation itself seems to work, but they get displayed wrongly.
As german is my mother tongue, I have to type several umlauts, beside any other special unicode-characters I definitely want to support.

As en example, I use linguist to translate *`over`* to *`über`*, and the resulting text in my application reads *`Ã¼ber`*. What I can surely recognize as an encoding mismatch.

I already had a look on the i18n example, which displays correctly for all of the provided languages, so I right now do not know what's wrong after I checked all file encodings.

Anyone any ideas? Or even has the same problems? Or had them but solved? Any suggestions were greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows-specific problem.
Instead of using QString.toStdString() (what breaks the correct string), better use QString.toLatin1() at least for the languages to support yet.